# Trip Advisor Scraping 'moreLink'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

I've been building a web scraper in BS4 and have gotten stuck.  I am using Trip Advisor as a test for other data I will be going after, but am not able to isolate the tag of the 'entire' reviews.  Here is an example:

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g56010-d470148-Reviews-Chez_Nous-Humble_Texas.html

Notice in the first review, there is an icon below "the wine list is...".  I am able to easily isolate the partial reviews, but have not been able to figure out a way to get BS4 to pull the reviews after a simulated 'More' click.  I'm trying to figure out what tool(s) are needed for this?  Do I need to use selenium instead?

The original element looks like this:

```
<span class="partnerRvw">
<span class="taLnk hvrIE6 tr475091998 moreLink ulBlueLinks" onclick="  ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(4444); ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.expandReviews', {type: 'dummy'}, ta.id('review_475091998'), 'review_475091998', '1', 4444);
  ">
More&nbsp; </span>
<span class="ui_icon caret-down"></span>
</span>
```

Looking at the HTML after you click on the More link you would find a new dynamically added class that has a  with the information I need (see below):

```
<div class="review dyn_full_review inlineReviewUpdate provider0 first newFlag" style="display: block;">
<a name="UR475091998" class=""></a>
<div id="UR475091998" class="extended provider0 first newFlag">
<div class="col1of2">
<div class="member_info">
<div id="UID_6875524F623CC948F4F9CA95BB4A9567-SRC_475091998" class="memberOverlayLink" onmouseover="requireCallIfReady('members/memberOverlay', 'initMemberOverlay', event, this, this.id, 'Reviews', 'user_name_photo');" data-anchorwidth="90">
<div class="avatar profile_6875524F623CC948F4F9CA95BB4A9567 ">
<a onclick="">

<img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-l/0d/97/43/bf/joannecarpenter.jpg" class="avatar potentialFacebookAvatar avatarGUID:6875524F623CC948F4F9CA95BB4A9567" width="74" height="74">
</a>
</div>
<div class="username mo">
<span class="expand_inline scrname mbrName_6875524F623CC948F4F9CA95BB4A9567" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('Reviews', 'show_reviewer_info_window', 'user_name_name_click')">joannecarpenter</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="location">
Humble, Texas
</div>
</div>
<div class="memberBadging g10n">
<div id="UID_6875524F623CC948F4F9CA95BB4A9567-CONT" class="no_cpu" onclick="ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie('15984'); requireCallIfReady('members/memberOverlay', 'initMemberOverlay', event, this, this.id, 'Reviews', 'review_count');" data-anchorwidth="90">
<div class="levelBadge badge lvl_02">
Level <span><img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/badges/20px/lvl_02.png" alt="" class="icon" width="20" height="20/"></span> Contributor </div>
<div class="reviewerBadge badge">
<img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/badges/20px/rev_03.png" alt="" class="icon" width="20" height="20">
<span class="badgeText">6 reviews</span> </div>
<div class="contributionReviewBadge badge">
<img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/badges/20px/Foodie.png" alt="" class="icon" width="20" height="20">
<span class="badgeText">6 restaurant reviews</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col2of2">
<div class="innerBubble">
<div class="quote"><a href="/ShowUserReviews-g56010-d470148-r475091998-Chez_Nous-Humble_Texas.html#CHECK_RATES_CONT" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('Reviews','title','',0,this.href); setPID();" id="r475091998">“<span class="noQuotes">Dinner</span>”</a></div>
<div class="rating reviewItemInline">
<span class="rate sprite-rating_s rating_s"> <img class="sprite-rating_s_fill rating_s_fill s50" width="70" src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="5 of 5 bubbles">
</span>
<span class="ratingDate relativeDate" title="April 12, 2017">Reviewed 3 days ago
<span class="new redesigned">NEW</span> </span>
<a class="viaMobile" href="/apps" target="_blank" onclick="ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(24687)">
<span class="ui_icon mobile-phone"></span>
via mobile
</a>
</div>
<div class="entry">
<p>
Our favorite restaurant in Houston. Definitely the best and friendliest service! The food is not only served with a flair, it is absolutely delicious. My favorite is the Lamb. It is the best! Also the duck moose, fois gras, the crispy salad and the French onion soup are all spectacular! This is a must try restaurant! The wine list is fantastic. Just ask Daniel for suggestions. He not only knows his wines; he loves what he does! We Love this place!
</p>
</div>
<div class="rating-list">
<div class="recommend">
<span class="recommend-titleInline noRatings">Visited April 2017</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="expanded lessLink">
<span class="taLnk collapse ulBlueLinks no_cpu ">
Less&nbsp;
</span>
<span class="textArrow_more ui_icon caret-up"></span>
</div>
<div id="helpfulq475091998_expanded" class="helpful redesigned white_btn_container ">
<span class="isHelpful">Helpful?</span> <div class="tgt_helpfulq475091998 rnd_white_thank_btn" onclick="ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.helpfulVoteHandlerOb', event, this, 'LeJIVqd4EVIpECri1GII2t6mbqgqguuuxizSxiniaqgeVtIJpEJCIQQoqnQQeVsSVuqHyo3KUKqHMdkKUdvqHxfqHfGVzCQQoqnQQZiptqH5paHcVQQoqnQQrVxEJtxiGIac6XoXmqoTpcdkoKAUAAv0tEn1dkoKAUAAv0zH1o3KUK0pSM13vkooXdqn3XmffAdvqndqnAfbAo77dbAo3k0npEEeJIV1K0EJIVqiJcpV1U0Ii9VC1rZlU3XozxbZZxE2crHN2TDUJiqnkiuzsVEOxdkXqi7TxXpUgyR2xXvOfROwaqILkrzz9MvzCxMva7xEkq8xXNq8ymxbAq8AzzrhhzCxbx2vdNvEn2fnwEfq8alzCeqi53ZrgnMrHhshTtowGpNSmq89IwiVb7crUJxdevaCnJEqI33qiE5JGErJExXKx5ooItGCy5wnCTx2VA7RvxEsO3'); ta.trackEventOnPage('HELPFUL_VOTE_TEST', 'helpfulvotegiven_v2');">
<img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/icons/icon_thumb_white.png" class="helpful_thumbs_up white">
<img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/icons/icon_thumb_green.png" class="helpful_thumbs_up green">
<span class="helpful_text">Thank joannecarpenter</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="tooltips vertically_centered">
<div class="reportProblem">
<span id="ReportIAP_475091998" class="problem collapsed taLnk" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('Report_IAP', 'Report_Button_Clicked', 'member'); ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.iapFlyout', event, this, '475091998')" onmouseover="if (!this.getAttribute('data-first')) {ta.trackEventOnPage('Reviews', 'report_problem', 'hover_over_flag'); this.setAttribute('data-first', 1)} uiOverlay(event, this)" data-tooltip="" data-position="above" data-content="Problem with this review?">
<img src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/icons/gray_flag.png" width="13" height="14" alt="">
<span class="reportTxt">Report</span> </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="userLinks">
<div class="sameGeoActivity">
<a href="/members-citypage/joannecarpenter/g56010" target="_blank" onclick="ta.setEvtCookie('Reviews','more_reviews_by_user','',0,this.href); ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(19160)">
See all 5 reviews by joannecarpenter for Humble </a>
</div>
<div class="askQuestion">
<span class="taLnk ulBlueLinks" onclick="ta.trackEventOnPage('answers_review','ask_user_intercept_click' ); ta.load('ta-answers', (function() {require('answers/misc').askReviewerIntercept(this, '470148', 'joannecarpenter', '6875524F623CC948F4F9CA95BB4A9567', 'en', '475091998','Chez Nous', 39151)}).bind(this), true);">Ask joannecarpenter about Chez Nous</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="note">
This review is the subjective opinion of a TripAdvisor member and not of TripAdvisor LLC. </div>
<div class="duplicateReviewsInline">
<div class="previous">joannecarpenter has 1 more review of Chez Nous</div> <ul class="dupReviews">
<li class="dupReviewItem">
<div class="reviewTitle">
<a href="/ShowUserReviews-g56010-d470148-r453237869-Chez_Nous-Humble_Texas.html#REVIEWS">“Joanne Carpenter”</a>
</div>
<div class="rating">
<span class="rate sprite-rating_ss rating_ss"> <img class="sprite-rating_ss_fill rating_ss_fill ss50" width="50" src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif" alt="5 of 5 bubbles">
</span>
<span class="date">Reviewed January 18, 2017</span>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="large">

</div>
<div class="ad iab_inlineBanner">
<div id="gpt-ad-468x60" class="adInner gptAd"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for BS4 to handle this for me?

Comment: BS4 is just an HTML parser; if you need to interact with the page to get the elements you need then yes, you'll need to use a browser driver like Selenium.

Comment: As I understand it, BS4 is just an HTML parser, so you'll n Ed something extra (or different) to handle this, as the extra data is probably loaded via Ajax. I see two approaches: you could check in your browser what that Ajax call is, and reproduce it in your code, or you could use something like phantomjs or casperjs to load the full page for you. The former is probably simpler, unless you anticipate you'll née to get a lot of different dynamic data from those pages.

Comment: Of course, usual disclaimer regarding the legal limits on what you can do with the data you're scraping.

Comment: What is the information that you need? Is it contained in the HTML that you obtain when you click on 'More'?

Comment: @BillBell, exactly.  After I hit more, HTML is dynamically added and a paragraph shows up with a longer review.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g56010-d470148-Reviews-Chez_Nous-Humble_Texas.html"
driver.get(url)

elem = driver.get_element_by_class_name("taLnk")
...
```

You could find more info about the methods here:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Thanks for the selenium solution.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood you will need to examine a few more of these pages, to identify variations in the HTML code. For the sample you have offered, and given that you are able to obtain it by simulating a press, the following code works to select the paragraph that you seem to want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HTML = open('temp.htm').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')

para = soup.select('.entry > p')
print (para[0].text)
```

Result:

Our favorite restaurant in Houston. Definitely the best and friendliest service! The food is not only served with a flair, it is absolutely delicious. My favorite is the Lamb. It is the best! Also the duck moose, fois gras, the crispy salad and the French onion soup are all spectacular! This is a must try restaurant! The wine list is fantastic. Just ask Daniel for suggestions. He not only knows his wines; he loves what he does! We Love this place!

Note that there are newlines before and after the paragraph.