# Can't get javascript generated html using python

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a python script that automatically gets the content of a table on a webpage.
I manage to have it to work on pure html page, but there is one website that gives me headache...
The html seems to be generated by javascript.
I tried dryscrape, selenium and qt4 libraries from examples found on several posts but still without success... I just get all the time the html before the javascript did his job.... so without tables....
I can see the table on the browser and when I do "Inspect" the html with Chrome. When I do "View Page Source" in Chrome the table is also not there... may be this can give some hints.

The website is the following:

https://www.ictax.admin.ch/extern/en.html#/security/CH0008899764/20161231

Here is some code I tried out (no table tags in the answer if you check):

Using urlib2:

```
import urllib2
url="https://www.ictax.admin.ch/extern/en.html#/security/CH0008899764/20161231"
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print html
```

Using dryscrape:

```
import dryscrape 
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit(url) 
response = session.body()
print response
```

Using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
print driver.page_source #page_source fetches page after rendering is complete
driver.quit()
```

Using PyQt4

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html 

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit() 

#This does the magic.Loads everything
r = Render(url)  
#result is a QString.
result = r.frame.toHtml()
#QString should be converted to string before processed by lxml
formatted_result = str(result.toAscii())
print formatted_result
```

I would appreciate so much if somebody could give me some help on this :-)

Cheers

Comment: Could you post some code you tried and didn't work?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423656/trip-advisor-scraping-morelink/43424006#43424006
You wanna try to use a PhantomJS driver to wait for the JS to load the page content.

Comment: @DeanFenster I posted some code that doesn't work (returns html without  the table)

Comment: Thanks for the link @elena! I tried it out but I get the same: html code in return, but no table in it... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an implicit wait (or an explicit one?) to wait for the page to load before searching for any elements:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
url = "https://www.ictax.admin.ch/extern/en.html#/security/CH0008899764/20161231"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("table").text)
```

This is the output I am getting:

> Titel/Titres/Titoli W Nominell Valoren-Nr. Steuerwert Ertrag /
>   Rendement / Reddito 2016 M Valeur No de Val. imposable Datum / Date
>   Cp. W Brutto KG/KEP zu versteuernder V nominale valeur Val. imposible
>   Data M Brut Ertrag/Rendement Valore Numero di 31.12.2016 ex. zahlb. V
>   lordo imposable/Reddito nominale valore pay. imponible CHF (E) pag.
>   Fr.W. CHF CHF   iShares ETF (CH) - iShares SMI (R) (CH), Schweiz
>   CHF 0.00 889 976 85.31 25.02. 29.02. 36 CHF     0.48
>             03.03. 07.03. 37 CHF     0.48
>             11.04. 13.04. 38 CHF     0.70
>             19.07. 21.07. 40 CHF   0.88
>             19.07. 21.07. 39 CHF     0.20